# Asp.net MVC Models to UML diagram

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, ef-code-first, uml

I am using .net MVC5 framework to develop applications. I searched but could not find any tools which, converts my code-first models to UML diagram? Is there build-in function in Visual Studio 2013 or any 3rd party tools ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Entity framwork power tools beta 4](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)
It will allow you to create a readonly edmx snapshot of you model.
I realize it's not UML but possibly enough for what you need.

In Visual studio click 'Tools > Extensions and Updates' then search for 'entity framework power tools' you should find it there to install.

Comment: Thank you, but i could not install it. It is VSIX file. How can i install ?

Comment: Thank you very much.But i think there is no extansion for VS 2013. No result found on search online items

Comment: What version of VS 2013 are you using? If it's express it may be a case of you not being able to use it - it's an assumption I have not tested.